# Error using TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult()

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, arguments

This is a follow-up question to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952493/using-async-bcl-with-async-function) regarding the use of an async wrapper over an async callback function.

Here is the code as it stands (an excellent solution provided by @Servy):

```
static Task<ObservableCollection<MyResult>> GetMyDataAsync(Params p)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<MyResult>>();
    DoStuffClass stuff = new DoStuffClass();
    stuff.LoadCompleted += (args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
    stuff.LongDrawOutProcessAsync(p);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

So, my problem is with the LoadCompleted event; here is the signature:

```
public event EventHandler<MyArgs> LoadCompleted;
```

`MyArgs` contains a property called ResultCollection; however, changing the code like this does not work:

```
    stuff.LoadCompleted += (args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args.ResultCollection);
```

In fact, I get the error:

```
'System.EventHandler<MyArgs>' does not take 1 arguments
```

Which I can see if correct from the signature; so how can I set the LoadCompleted result to the `TaskCompletionSource`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) needs 2 arguments, the first is the instance that raised the event and the second is the event arguments. You need to specify both of them even if you only use one (`args`).
This should work:

```
stuff.LoadCompleted += (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
```

Comment: got me by a few seconds

Answer (score 2):

```
stuff.LoadCompleted += (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
```

This should fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `EventHandler<T>` definition you will see it takes two arguments

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(object sender, TEventArgs e);
```

So you need to pass two arguments in your assignment

```
stuff.LoadCompleted += (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
```